# c# - concatenation and properties of TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, textbox, web

I'm trying to use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    string x + i = TextBox + i.Text;
}
```

Is there any solution for this?  I want to use `i` as an index as if I had an array of `TextBox`.  How can I achieve a textbox's Text property like this?

I want to create for example a string named x1,x2,x3,x4... and value of x1 = TextBox1.Text.
But I could not :(

I have TextBox1,2,3...40 and I just want to pass their text values to new string or string list ex. like x1 = TextBox1.Text, x2 = TextBox2.Text; ..... :(

Comment: You should explain the problem. What is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by string x+i inside a loop? String[] ?

Comment: It should be noted that your code does not compile. I took the liberty of cleaning it up and rephrasing your question, which I believe is that you want to index into an array of `TextBox`.

Comment: I never seen syntax like that? Are you from python or perl background?

Comment: He wants to create dynamically named variables (or use ones already created) and access `TextBox`es that are named similarly.

Comment: i think you should use repeater instead of textbox array. if you can

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get the `Text` property from a collection of `TextBox` - which, by the way, you haven't shown us how you're getting.  It's possible that you don't even **have** an array of `TextBox`.

If you do, you'd use code like this (note that `SomeCodeToGetTextBoxArray()` needs to be defined by you):

```
TextBox[] myTextBoxes = SomeCodeToGetTextBoxArray();
var arrayLength = myTextBoxes.Length;
String[] x = new String[arrayLength];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    x[i] = myTextBoxes[i].Text;
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling he doesn't have an array of `TextBox`es, which would lead him to need reflection. But I'm still gonna upvote you're answer because he really **should** use arrays (or `List<T>`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is have a reference to a local variable, field, or property by it's string name that you generate at runtime. The only way to do what you want is to use reflection.

There are different ways to do this depending on if the variable is locally scoped, a field member, or a property member.

Reflection - [`LocalVariableInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.localvariableinfo.aspx) - [`FieldInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.aspx) - [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx)

---

Note that while that would be the answer to your question, it is probably better to use an array (or `List<T>`) and use indexes. Though, it is really impossible to know without knowing what you are trying to do fully (not just in your little snippet). But, it's more likely that an array (or `List<T>`) is the more correct solution.